# Returning True for only 1 Function out of the list of 3

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming

Since I'm pretty sure that using global variables in Haskell is frowned upon. I'm wondering is there anyway I can achieve the following?

```
-- list has elements that are odd
listHasOdd :: [Integer] -> Bool
-- list has elements that are even
listHasEven :: [Integer] -> Bool
--list has a length > 5
longList :: [Integer] -> Bool

-- Maps the function to a [Bool]
-- This function cannot be modified to fix the problem.
checkList :: [Integer] -> [Bool]
checkList xs = map (\ y -> y xs) listChecker
where listChecker = [listHasOdd, listHasEven, longList]
```

Is there anyway that I can ensure that only one of them returns true?

> For example, [1,2,3,5], I would want only want listHasOdd to return
>   True which is [True, False, False]. (Evaluated from top to bottom).
>
> Another example, [2,4,6,8,10,12,14], the returns should be [False, True, False].
>
> In other words, checkList [1,2,3,5] returns [True, False, False], checkList[2,4,6,8,10,12,14] returns [False, True, False]
>
> **The last function would always be False in my example, since it is unreachable.

I know I can do an if statement to check if the previous one is `True` but that seems like a pretty dumb idea. Or is that actually the way to do it? (Considering Haskell "remembers" the results of the previous function)

Comment: and?  http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:and

Comment: Hm, you might have seen the question before I've updated it. Made it clearer now. `and` would really satisfy what I want when I'm returning a list of `bool`.

Comment: So you want to actually have `map (\y -> y xs, unless a previous function alreadyreturned True, in which case False)`?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you want.  Only one of what returns true?  List lists of numbers and you desired output please.

Comment: @DanielFischer, I believe I have a restriction of not being allowed to modify the checkList function.

Comment: If you want it not to check if listHasEven, then you can just use and because haskell is lazy.  It will not check the others if one is false.

Comment: Are we allowed to modify `listChecker`?

Comment: @dave4420 Nope, no parts of checkList can be modified.

Comment: Are we allowed to change the definitions of `listHasEven` and `longList` from the obvious to something that checks the results of calling the previous function(s) in the list? That would be a stupid way of doing it, but if you gotta adhere to a stupid rule...

Comment: @dave4420 Yeah, I'm allowed to do anything with any other function except for listChecker. I'm aware of that solution too but it just seems too stupid to be correct.

Comment: Using global variables in Haskell is not really frowned upon, because it's impossible.

Comment: I've just realised that `longList = const False`. *\*sigh\**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the best I can come up with. It generalises relatively painlessly to handle the number of possible outcomes of a poker hand, for example.

```
data Outcome
    = ListHasOdd
    | ListHasEven
    | LongList
    | Nope
  deriving Eq

outcomeFromList :: [Integer] -> Outcome
outcomeFromList xs
    | any odd xs    = ListHasOdd
    | any even xs   = ListHasEven
    | 5 < length xs = LongList
    | otherwise     = Nope

listHasOdd = (ListHasOdd ==) . outcomeFromList
listHasEven = (ListHasEven ==) . outcomeFromList
longList = (LongList ==) . outcomeFromList
```

But even this is stupid: instead of generating a `[Bool]`, why not just use the `Outcome` directly?

---

**Edit:** Or we could pay attention to what the functions *mean*.

```
listHasOdd xs = any odd xs

listHasEven [] = False
listHasEven xs = all even xs
-- if not all of them are even, then at least one must be odd,
-- and `listHasOdd` would give `True`

longList _ = False
-- if the list has at least 5 elements,
-- then either the list has at least one odd element
-- (and `listHasOdd` would give `True`)
-- or the list has at least five even elements
-- (and `listHasEven` would give `True`)
```

Comment: I'm choosing this answer over the other is because it "matches" my original question a lot better.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the point of it, but

```
foldr foo [] $ map ($ xs) [listHasOdd, listHasEven, longList]
  where
    foo True zs = True : map (const False) zs
    foo False zs = False : zs
```

would produce the desired result, and it would only evaluate the functions until one of them returned `True` (or the end of the list of functions is reached).

Comment: Doesn't this solution require modifications to checkList? (Which I'm not allowed to do). Unless I do this for listHasEven and longList. (Which is basically the same as calling each function every single time - Something I'm trying to avoid if possible).

Comment: If you can't modify `checkList` at all, and can't post-process the result of `checkList`, the only way to achieve the desired result would be to have `listHasEven xs = not (listHasOdd xs) && any even xs`, and include both other functions in `longList`. May I ask what the goal is, and what precisely the demands and restrictions?

Comment: This is basically a "toned-down" version of a more complex problem - such as calculation of points for a card game. If for example, the hand is a straight flush, I wouldn't want to calculate it as a straight flush + straight + flush. I'm basically given listChecker and I'm told to implement listHasEven and listHasOdd.

Comment: The right way to handle it is probably to not care. You probably need to _consume_ the result of `checkList` only until you encounter the first `True`. Then you needn't bother about anything in `checkList`'s result thereafter, these function calls will not be evaluated [not even the thunks for them created] unless you look at the result in some way.

Comment: What do you mean by not care? As is modify checkList? I was initially wondering if there was some `special way` to do this in Haskell. I'll probably get clarification on whether or not I'm allowed to modify checkList. Thanks.

Comment: I meant "not care" as in "use `checkList` as is", there is probably no reason why you should have only one `True` in the list. It seems you try to solve the wrong problem with that.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve. Not "have only one `True` in the result", but _why_ would that matter?

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware that there are a lot of better ways to solve this problem but this is more of an homework assignment than anything else. I've been a precise set of functions to implement and these implementations should return a precise result. Which only has one single `True`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26967/discussion-between-daniel-fischer-and-user1043625)